# Translating coordinates from tilted axis system

Tags: geometry, rotations

I am programming in Processing and I need a bit of help in mathematics.
What I have is a standard axis system with the axes x and y, but tilted by r degrees. If I draw a point at (100, 100), it will draw it according to the altered axes, meaning it won't be at (100, 100) in the upright system.

Now, if I want to pick any point the normal system, I want to calculate the coordinates of the point in the altered system, so that I can easily fill those in and it will be in the place my upright-mind wants them to be.

I know the calculations for it aren't supposed to be difficult, but I just can't figure it out. How do I calculate x' and y'?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis of the "unaltered" system is:
$$
i=(1, 0)\quad\textrm{and}\quad j=(0, 1) 
$$
This can be put in a matrix, let's call it $I$:
$$
I=
\begin{bmatrix}
i & j
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let $u$ and $v$ the vectors that form the basis of the "altered" system. You said it is tilted by an angle, let's call it $\theta$. If you try to picture the trigonometric circle, and rotate the vector $i$ of an angle of $\theta$, you can immediately see that its coordinate now are $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and $(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$ for $j$.

So what you did is basically multiply $i$ and $j$ by a matrix $R$:
$$
R=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Indeed:
$$
RI=R
$$
So the basis of you rotated system is $A$:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
u & v
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What you did for the basis will work with any vector (and thus any point).

Let $p$ a point in $(i, j)$. Multiply it by $A$, and you will obtain its coordinates in the rotated system:
$$
Ap
$$

So you want to know the coordinates of a point in a new basis, put that basis in a matrix form and multiply it by the point.

Comment: It's funny to see these old questions of mine and how plainly obvious it is to me now. I got out of high school when I wrote this question and am almost done with an IT degree in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If the rotation is counterclockwise by angle $\alpha$ and $(x,y)$ are the coordinates in the original axes and $(x', y')$ are the coordinates in the new (transformed) axes, then:

$x' = x \cos\alpha + y \sin\alpha$

$y' = y\cos\alpha - x\sin\alpha$